# What is the best way to get numbers from a sentence?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm just trying to get the numbers that are in a sentence.

They can be currency, regular numbers, + and -.

Example would be:

Gym membership **7** months @**$20** per month **$140.00**

Gym membership refund **$-100.00**

I've been using this expression:

\$?(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{3}(.\d{0,2})?|\d{1,3}(.\d{2})?)

I've been using this website to test it.

http://rubular.com/

The only problem is it doesn't pick up **$-100.00,** it only picks up **100.00**.

I'm also interested if there is a better way to do this or is this the only way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> \$?**-?**(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{3}(.\d{0,2})?|\d{1,3}(.\d{2})?)

Just add a `-?` there.

Whether there is a better way depends on what your requirements are. If this is working fine for you and does everything you want, I see no reason to use something else.

Comment: that should do it, though it would allow things like $-10 per month.

Comment: @Fallenreaper heck, it would even allow things like "Gym membership for $7 months", because it's reading _numbers_, not _english_ :)